# Unable to run a javascript file from docker to populate mongo db using WSL shell (windows 10)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker

I am trying to run a script to populate my mongo db but everytime i get those errors, when i do docker ps the container is up and running:

Note: i'm on windows 10 using WSL shell

[image]

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks a lot.

This is the import_script.js that i am trying to run :

```
use ulaval

db.professeurs.insert(
    [{
        "prenom":"Etienne",
        "nom":"Marceau",
        "cours":"ACT-3000",
        "faculte":"fsg",
        "ecole":"ulaval",
        "cours_derniere_session":["ACT-7002","ACT-2001"]
    },
    {
        "prenom":"Jean-Thomas",
        "nom":"Baillargeon",
        "cours":"GLO-4035",
        "faculte":"fsg",
        "ecole":"ulaval",
        "age":32
    },
    {
        "prenom":"Julie",
        "nom":"Langevin",
        "faculte":"fmd",
        "ecole":"ulaval"
    },
    {
        "prenom":"Richard",
        "nom":"Khoury",
        "faculte":"fsg",
        "ecole":"ulaval",
        "cours_derniere_session":["GLO-7027"]
    },
    {
        "prenom":"Luc",
        "nom":"Lamontagne",
        "cours":"IFT-7022",
        "faculte":"fsg",
        "ecole":"ulaval"
    },
    {
        "prenom":"Philippe",
        "nom":"Gregoire",
        "cours":"GSF-2103",
        "faculte":"fsa",
        "ecole":"ulaval"
    },
    {
        "prenom":"Philippe",
        "nom":"Gregoire",
        "cours":"GSF-2103",
        "faculte":"fsa",
        "ecole":"ulaval"
    }]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to windows line breaks (`CRLF`) which are used in your javascript file https://prnt.sc/1sc3w17.
Mongo shell runner (if you run it inside of docker container based on Linux) requires UNIX style line breaks (`LF`) that's why you see the syntax errors. You can replace line endings manually in any text editor or use some console tool like this one `dos2unix` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dos2unix

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix